# c++ How could I properly predefined array of char*?

Tags: c++, c, constants, string-literals

I am doing it that way:

```
int argc = 9;
char* argv[argc];

argv[0] = "c:/prog.exe";
```

but I get notice, that it is deprecated. What is better way?

Comment: This actually isn't valid c++.  Using variables to declare size of an array on the stack is part of a newer C standard that isn't integrated yet with the latest C++ one.  Are you sure you've used the right tag?

Comment: @Noah Roberts: It's probably a language extension implemented by the compiler (which may explain why it's deprecated).

Comment: Isn't "integrated" as far as the standards are concerned. But the major compilers support this, so I'd be smooth on this one (and that's not the OP's problem here btw).

Comment: The warning's not related to VLAs at all, see my post and Vlad's.

Comment: @In silico - no, what's deprecated is non-const string literals.  Deprecated by the standard in 03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either make it const:

```
const char *argv[] = { "Arg1", "Arg2", "..." };
```

... or not use the constant string literals:

```
int argc = 9;
char* argv[argc];
char prog_name[] = "c:/prog.exe";
argv[0] = prog_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the problem of using something other than a constant expression for your array size...

The thing that has been deprecated is the silent casting of string literals to `char*`.  This used to be OK:

```
char * hello = "hello";
```

Now it has to be:

```
char const* hello = "hello";
```

This deprecation is actually in an Appendix in C++03.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `const` to indicate that the strings won't be modified.

```
const char* argv[] = { "c:/prog.exe" };
const int argc = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0]);

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        ::printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Here, `argc` will also be calculated at compile time automatically so there's a lesser chance of error (thanks to Goz for the suggestion).

Comment: Won't `sizeof(argv)` be (typically) 4 or 8 depending on architecture (size of pointer)?

Comment: "const int argc = sizeof( argv ) / sizeof( argv[0] );" would mean a little less possibilities of a mistake :)

Comment: @Mark B: Yes. I had a brain fart. :-P @Goz: Thanks, I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let analyze what you are doing here:

```
// Create an int with value 9.
int argc = 9;

// Create an array of char* pointers of size 9
char* argv[argc];

// Assign the the first pointer to the global data string "C:\prog.exe"
argv[0] = "c:/prog.exe";
```

My guess is that you are not trying to do what I've described above. Try something like this:

```
// create an array of characters
char argv[] = "C:/prog.exe";

// argc in now the length of the string
int argc = sizeof argv;
```

-or -

```
// create an array of strings
char* argv[] = {"C:/prog.exe"};
// argc is now the number of strings in the array
int argc = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Vlad.

Some more explanation from me on what happens here:

You get the "deprecated" warning, because such code:

```
"asdf"
```

now has type `const char*`, not `char*`. And string literals can be converted to `char*`, to retain some compatibility with the older conventions when `const` wasn't that strict. But conversion of a string literal to `char*` from `const char*` is deprecated and you should not rely on it.

Why? String literal is a pointer to constant memory, that's why it needs to be `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Other than what everyone else has pointed out about const string literals being assigned to non-const char pointers and the weirdness of declaring argv and argc outside of main()'s parameter list, there is an additional problem with this line here:

`char* argv[argc];`

You can only use integer constant expressions for array sizes in C++; an integer constant expression being a literal integer in the source of your program (like "5" or "10"), an enumerations value (like "red" from "enum colors {red, green, blue};"), a sizeof expression, or an int variable declared with const:

```
// can hold 30 ints
int myarray1[30];

// can hold as many ints as myarray1 is wide in bytes
int myarray2[sizeof(myarray1)];

// C++ does not support variable-length arrays like C99 does, so if an int
// variable is used to specify array size, it must be marked const:
const int myarray3_size = 42;
int myarray3[myarray3];
```

Many C++ compilers implement C99-style variable-length arrays, so you may not get any complaint when you use them, but they are still best avoided if you want to write portable code.